# actions vs. fragment changes in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

So, I followed a tutorial to add a sliding navigation drawer to my app (plus did some tweaking of my own), but I'm a bit confused, possibly because I don't totally grok fragments.  Basically I created an overflow menu with Log Out as the only option, so I could test my login system.  I want that log out option in my navigation drawer so I can just get rid of that that overflow menu, but I can't figure out what to change so that it logs out instead of just displays the title of the fragment that was clicked on.  And while I'm asking basically the same question, if I wanted to create the page that someone is viewing when they click on an option in the navigation drawer, where would I do that?  In the respective fragment?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
             if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();
            }

        else {
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding. add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "About"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_logout_black_48dp, "Log Out"));
        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);


        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //set title
        setTitle(listSliding.get(0).getTitle());
        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //set title
                setTitle(listSliding.get(position).getTitle());
                //item selected
                listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //close menu
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.action_logout) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment3** (I tried adding the logout option to this fragment but to no avail. Still what happens when I click it is the text "Log Out" displays on the screen)

```
package me.paxana.alerta.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.parse.ParseUser;

import me.paxana.alerta.LoginActivity;
import me.paxana.alerta.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Fragment3.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Fragment3#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment3() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Fragment3.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Fragment3 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment3 fragment = new Fragment3();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Fragment3.this.getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you're looking for, you can log out by clicking the log-out element of the Navigation Drawer List:

Try this:

```
listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          if (position == logOutIndex) { //You can do this if you know the position of the logOut button, e.g it's always at the end of the ListVIew

                ParseUser.logOut();
                navigateToLogin();
           }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that it works:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId == R.id.action_logout) {
        //ParseUser.logOut();
        //navigateToLogin();
        //If you the latest activity was te LoginActivity it goues to the LoginActivity
           finish();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Or if you is trying to do it from the drawer, replace you fragment3 by this:

```
 private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragment = new Fragment3();
              //If you the latest activity was te LoginActivity it goues to the LoginActivity

               finish();

            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: yeah I want to do it from the drawer, the overflow menu logout button works correctly presently.  So i'm a little but confused about what to put after case 2.

Comment: Are you trying to do a logout in case 2 isn't? the case 2 is the label "log out" Can you post a capture image?.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to explain because you have to do so much to get it work.
The first idea I have is that you paste your code to log out into the **switch case** in the ***MainActivity.java***:

```
private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            ParseUser.logOut();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Fragment3.this.getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
               mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
               mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
    }
    if(null != fragment) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        ...
```

I hope I understood you right but this has to fix the problem and if you now click on the 3rd fragment your logout has to be made.

If I am wrong write back soon and I will look for another solution ;)